# Bind data to the ListView control in WPF using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have tried to bind the data into the `ListView` control:

```
<ListView Margin="8" Height="400" Width="650" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyData}">
    <ListView.View>
         <GridView>
             <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="Auto" 
                  DisplayMemberBinding="Binding Path=ID}" >
             </GridViewColumn>
             <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" 
                  Header="Name" Width="100"/>
             <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Price}" 
                  Header="Price" Width="100"/>
             <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Author}" 
                  Header="Author" Width="100"/>
             <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Catalog}" 
                  Header="Catalog" Width="100"/>
           </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>

  ObservableCollection<TableInfo> _MyData
  public ObservableCollection<TableInfo> MyData{ get; set; }
```

However, it's not display anything in the window but `MyData` is an `ObservableCollection`. How do I bind the data?

Comment: I think you are missing some code there. And use two enters to separate code and text. ;)

Comment: I'm assuming the second open tag of `<ListView.View>` isn't meant to be there?

Comment: mistakely i have add the second open tag <ListView.View>. now edited

Comment: What is the type of MyData? How do you bind your view model to the view above? Is MyData empty/null by any chance?

Comment: MyData is a property available in the view Class

Comment: yeap.. i have set datacontext. its executing fine and the collection contains data but it not displaying in the listview

Comment: Take a look at the binding in [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/). It's really good at allowing you to essentially debug bindings and find errors at runtime.

Comment: just implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface and raise the propertychanged in the Setter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tanya,

If you set your view model properly and if you're sure that your MyData collection is not null or empty, try to remove the "Path" keywords from your xaml:

```
<ListView Margin="8" Height="400" Width="650" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyData}">
    <ListView.View>
         <GridView>
             <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="Auto" 
                  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" >
             </GridViewColumn>
             <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" 
                  Header="Name" Width="100"/>
             <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price}" 
                  Header="Price" Width="100"/>
             <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Author}" 
                  Header="Author" Width="100"/>
             <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Catalog}" 
                  Header="Catalog" Width="100"/>
           </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

If this doesn't help, check the debug output and post it, we will definitely figure something out.

Comment: No errors thrown in the output window. and also no details about the binding.

Comment: If so, your MyData collection must be empty. can you set a breakpoint on the getter of this property? Does it even stop there?

Comment: yeah.. After assign the data. its not breaking there in the getter of the MyData property

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this. After assigning data context (your view model)? Could you post the content of your TableView class? Additionally, could you post the code where you actually bind the view model to the view (the whole constructor or whatever you use)?

Comment: Regarding OnPropertyChanged - it should state OnPropertyChanged("MyData");

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6612/discussion-between-piotr-justyna-and-tanya)

Answer (score 1):

Your `XAML` looks fine to me.

Make sure you are setting the `DataContext` correctly.

```
yourView.DataContext = YouViewModel;
```

Comment: ya i have added those lines in the xaml. but even then its not displaying anything yar. But the collection contains data

Comment: `  Tableview view = new TableView();
            this.DataContext = view;`

Comment: yes..Its the view model which contains the observableCollection

Comment: Take a look at output windows. It states if there are any broken bindings. It might help

Comment: Shouldn't it be in the form: <UserControl.DataContext>
      <vm:VIEWMODELNAME />
</UserControl.DataContext> ?

Answer (score 0):

When the Binding is first evaluated, it may (depending on your code) find null. It does not get notified if you later set it to something sensible.

Try to make sure that you create the ObservableCollection in your classes costructor and not overwrite it somewhere else. You could alternativly implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise a PropertyChanged event on te MyData setter.