# How to set specific item in a ListView using MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I have a ListView of Button elements like this:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DummyModelList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
     <ListViewItem >
          <Button Name="test" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" Command="{Binding DataContext.TestCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}">
               <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                         <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" x:Name="bg">
                              <Image Source="{Binding DataContext.SlidOnOffImg , RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}"/>
                         </Grid>
                   </ControlTemplate>
               </Button.Template>
          </Button>
     </ListViewItem >
```

In my ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel:BindableBase
 {

        private ObservableCollection<Slide> dummyModelList;
        public ObservableCollection<Slide> DummyModelList 
        {
            get { return dummyModelList; }
            set 
            { 
                dummyModelList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => DummyModelList);
            }
        } 

        public string SlidOnOffImg { get; set; }


        private int selectedItem;
        public int SelectedItem //this property stores currently selected item from thumbnails list
        {
            get { return selectedItem; }

            set
            {
                selectedItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => SelectedItem);
            }

        public CompositeCommand TestCommand { get; set; }

        public MyViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager, IEventAggregator eventAggregator) //constructor
        {

            dummyModelList = new ObservableCollection<ISlide>() { new Slide(), new Slide(), new Slide()};

            TestCommand = new CompositeCommand();
            TestCommand.RegisterCommand(new DelegateCommand(ChangeImage));
        }

        private void ChangeImage()
        {

            if (dummyModelList.ElementAt(selectedItem).SlideExcluded)
                dummyModelList.ElementAt(selectedItem).SlideExcluded = false;
            else
                dummyModelList.ElementAt(selectedItem).SlideExcluded = true;

            SlidOnOffImg = dummyModelList.ElementAt(selectedItem).SlideONOFFImgPath;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => SlidOnOffImg);
        }
}
```

In my model:

```
public class Slide : ISlide
{
    public bool SlideExcluded { get; set; }

    public string SlideONOFFImgPath 
    {
        get
        {
            if(SlideExcluded)
                return "/Assets/Visible_OFF.png";
            else
                return "/Assets/Visible_ON.png";
        }

    }

}
```

My goal is to have button's image to toggle between two image paths on button click. It works, but the problem is that all the buttons in the list change the image path on some button click. I want only the one that is clicked to change the image path.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be binding to SelectedIndex instead of SelectedItem in your XAML. SelectedIndex holds a reference to the index for the item in the list, SelectedItem holds a reference to the object in the list. Either that, or change your view model to work with the actual object rather than the index.

Comment: I changed to SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" but it still doesn't work the way I want.

Comment: It looks like you may need to adjust what property you are binding to for the image path. Test_ImagePath or SlidOnOffImg.

Comment: In your XAML, the binding is this: Source="{Binding DataContext.Test_ImagePath... Is that right. I don't see that property (Test_ImagePath) in the view model, or model.

Comment: Yes, sorry it was a typo. I meant it to be 'SlidOnOffImg'

Comment: It works, but as I said, it updates all buttons in the ListView. I assume there must be a way to tell the ListViewItem in XAML to bind to a property only if it selected....

Comment: I think I see now. The list is binding to a property in the view model that is being used by all of the items in the list. The binding path needs to change to get the image path from the model. Slide.SlideONOFFImgPath, or something along that line.

Comment: Yes, I see. So just for testing, I created ObservableCollection 'TestList' and added 3 hardcoded strings for image paths. Then in XAML I do this: '<Image Source="{Binding DataContext.TestList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}"/>' but it didn't work

Comment: I think you need to do this: <Image Source="{Binding SlideONOFFImgPath, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}"/> Or, maybe even just this: <Image Source="{Binding SlideONOFFImgPath}"/>

Comment: Well, no...it didn't work....because SlideONOFFImgPath is model property and XAML know nothing about it

Comment: If you want this to work like you want, then you have to get that property value bound to the list at the item/model level. Binding to that value at the view model level will not work, as you have seen. You have one view model, but many items in the list/collection, thus many models. The binding must happen at the model. That way, when you change the image path value for one model, only one item in the list updates.

Comment: So my idea is to create some kind of observable collection in ViewModel that will hold individual image paths collected from model objects for each button in the listView. I just don't know how to bind to this collection properly in XAML....

Comment: It looks like you are already there. The ItemSource is binding to your collection in the view model. Just use normal binding in the list view item control template to show the things you want to show. Like this: <Image Source="{Binding SlideONOFFImgPath}"/>. A simple example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818499/bind-data-to-the-listview-control-in-wpf-using-mvvm

Comment: ok, so my question actually boils down to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36763660/how-to-bind-each-buttons-image-source-from-listview-to-individual-item-from-obs