# How to bind each button's image source from ListView to individual item from observable collection?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a Listview of Buttons like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TestList}">
     <ListViewItem >
         <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Name="test" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent">
                        <Button.Template>
                             <ControlTemplate>
                                  <Grid>
                                      <Image Source="?????????????????????????????????????????????"/>
                                  </Grid>
                               </ControlTemplate>
                       </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

And the code behind like this:

```
public class CodeBehind
 {

        private ObservableCollection<string> testList;
        public ObservableCollection<string> TestList 
        {
            get { return testList; }
            set 
            { 
                testList = value;
            }
        } 



        public CodeBehind()
        {

            dummyModelList = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "/Assets/Image1", "/Assets/Image2", "/Assets/Image3"};


        }


}
```

How to bind each button's image source to individual item from observable collection? I want to do this only in XAML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`ItemTemplate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) (Gets or sets the DataTemplate used to display each item.) instead of buttons' template itself.

You use the ItemTemplate to specify the visualization of the data objects. If your ItemsControl is bound to a collection object and you do not provide specific display instructions using a DataTemplate, the resulting UI of each item is a string representation of each object in the underlying collection.

So when you set the ItemTemplate to an instance of DataTemplate, the DataTemplate will be used to render the items. The DataContext of the DataTemplate will be implicitly set to individual items in the bound collection, so you can bind the `Image.Source` to the DataContext itself using `{Binding .}` or `{Binding}`

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TestList}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Name="test" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent">
                   <Image Source="{Binding .}" />
              </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Yes, I already used ItemTemplate, but forgot to include it in my question. Please see updated code. I'll try your solution shortly

Comment: If u already use it, `{Binding .}` or `{Binding}` will work because you will be binding to the `DataContext` which will be the string itself.

Comment: Sorry, just one more thing...and I know I should probably ask it in new question, but how if I have two buttons in each ListViewElement, and I want to bind each one of them to two different observable collections? This means that somehow I should bind ItemSource to two different collections, but how?

Comment: You can't do that. If you have two buttons each displaying a different image, I suggest you change your observable collection -> `ObservableCollection<SomeModelClass>` where `SomeModelClass` will contain properties for the two image paths.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you!

Comment: can you just show me how would Binding for Image Source in XAML look like in that case?

Comment: When your ObservableCollection consists of models having properties, you want to bind to individual properties. The DataContext in this case will be the Model. So something like this `<Image Source="{Binding Source1}"...` where `Source1` is a string in your Model class.

Comment: Ok, so if I use MVVM and I bind directly to the model property in XAML, is this going to break the pattern? Because I think, View should know nothing about the Model

Comment: Oh well, I don't see any problem with view knowing about model. The purpose of View is to display out logic. View knowing anything about viewmodel or model will not hinder unit testing afaik. 

My MVVM way is that view can know about both model and viewmodel but viewmodel and model should not know about view. Model should not know about viewmodel, but viewmodel can know about model.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: I did it and it works exactly the way I want. the only thing that worries me is that the model is now coupled with Prism framework, since inside the model I must call 'OnPropertyChanged'.

Comment: I don't know about you, but I implement OnPropertyChanged myself most of the times (For models). It's just 3-4 lines. So the model is decoupled from everything.

Comment: If you don't want that, you can always wrap your models using a viewmodel, but I think that's just overkill because we achieve nothing except following MVVM like religion :p (It's also way more verbose than implementing INotifyPropertyChanged ourselves

Comment: The `OnPropertyChanged` can me a single line => `this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));`
You call it like so :  `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.MyProperty))`. That's all.

Comment: Yes, for now I wrap it using separate ViewModel, but later I'll definitely consider other method that you explained.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `DataTemplate` to show any controls in your `ItemTemplate` of `ListView`:

```
<ListView Name="listView">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Grid Margin="2">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto*"/>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <Button>           
              <Image Source="{Binding AddressImage}" Width="20" Grid.Row="0" />
           </Button>
           <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" TextAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Light"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding UserName}" />
         </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Model:

```
public class Person
{
public int IdUser {get; set;}
public string UserName {get; set;}
public string AddressImage {get; set;}
}
```

code-behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
   PopulateCollection();
}

private void PopulateCollection()
{
    ObservableCollection<Person> personColl = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
         //here you can set any image what you want
         personColl.Add(new Person() { IdUser=i, UserName="I am " + i.ToString(), 
                    AddressImage="Assets/1.png"});
         //Assets is a folder with images
    }
    listView.ItemsSource=personColl;
}
```